# Why the name "category"?

Tags: category-theory, notation, terminology

I'm reading about category theory. A question I don't see answered anywhere is about the choice of the word "category" in this context. Why this concept was named "category"?

Comment: They're just supposed to be different categories of mathematical objects in the colloquial sense, e.g. groups, rings, topological spaces. I don't think it's particularly deep.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The answer from Geoff suggests that the etymology is in fact pretty interesting, somewhat deep.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Maybe you're right. Groups are another example. The colloquial concept of "group" anticipates nothing about its meaning in mathematics, I think.

Answer (score 6):

The term ``category'' came from the Kantian perspective on a category being the most general form of thinking, although I may be mistaken on the finer points of the actual philosophy there. This is discussed in this [philosophy.stackexchange post here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/49180/why-were-kants-categories-used-in-the-mathematical-category-theory)  (see the accepted answer in particular) which speaks far more eloquently on the subject than I could hope to mimic.

Comment: Thanks, that link is a very interesting discussion!

Comment: I find this quote from the linked OP particularly illuminating: 

*... my guess is that categories in mathematics don't usually mention individual elements of a set explicitly. They only define properties of elements via how various sets relate to each other. This in turn defines the elements.*